# How to make all activities(except MainActivity) have ActionBar/Toolbar at once with a title and a back button? (Xamarin.Android)

Tags: xamarin.android, android-actionbar, toolbar, title, back-button

Yesterday I asked the same question but I forgot to say that it was for Xamarin.Android, not for Android(JAVA) (sorry about that) and the solution I got was for Android(JAVA) but I can't implement it on Xamarin.Android. I didn't delete the question, I left it just in case someone in the future needs it for Android, but I want to know the solution for Xamarin.Android.

I have the following `MainActivity`:

[image]

When I click on "Congreso" button the following activity appears:

[image]

And when I click on "Programa" button the following activity appears:

[image]

All activities except `MainActivity` have an action bar with a back button, a title of the activity aligned at the same place each time and the same color of the action bar. In my case I want the color to be blue. My question is, is there a way to set that behaviour on a single place in the application and it to apply to all the activities except for the `MainActivity` so that if some day I want to change the color of the action bar or the alignement of its title I don't have to go to all activities one by one and change it.

P.S.: I don't know if what is on the screenshots is an action bar or it is a toolbar. If you give me a solution with a toolbar it is OK too.

Comment: Do it in one base activity and inherit the rest from it and you should be good

Comment: A little more detail, please.

Comment: @Montoolivo I have checked your asked another question , and this shared [link](https://medium.com/@sandeeptengale/writing-good-baseactivity-class-for-android-activity-100636c81011) also can be refer to Xamarin.Amdroid . You just need to transfer a little code to C# . By the way , you can try to refer link to write code in project .If occurs problems when running code  , you can update question here .